# flutter list payment paypal

Tags: flutter, paypal

i am trying to get a paypal payment list in flutter, but i can't get it.
This is the documentation:
[doc paypal api](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/)

but I don't know where I'm wrong.
This is my code:

```
var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(
          "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment?count=10&start_index=0&sort_by=create_time&sort_order=desc"),
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
      });
```

I'm getting a 400's error: INVALID_REQUEST
a help? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the nonsense I realized now that it is of type get and not post.
Correct code:

```
var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
          "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment?count=10&start_index=0&sort_by=create_time&sort_order=desc"),
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
      });
```